# GroupBy ID, then Create columns based on values inside rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Im trying to turn this spark Dataframe:

```
ID  STATUS  COUNT
a     1      3
a     2      2
b     2      4
c     3      5
d     1      3
d     2      3
```

Into this:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| ID|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  3|  2|  0|
|  b|  0|  4|  0|
|  c|  0|  0|  5|
|  d|  3|  3|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I'm relatively new to this, I thinking of doing something along the lines of:

```
df.withColumnRenamed("1", udf_sum_val1)
  .withColumnRenamed("2", udf_sum_val2)
  .withColumnRenamed("2", udf_sum_val3)
```

Then doing a groupBy, and summing all the values.

Then doing some kind of groupBys, but this does not feel correct. I am wondering if someone could chime in with a better approach?

Comment: what you need is pivoting, see https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html

Comment: Thank you! Was not at all familiar at all with this. I was about to add all the columns with the counts and then run a sum - this is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do (your example is somewhat unclear), but it sounds like pivoting:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", 1, 3),
  ("a", 2, 2),
  ("b", 2, 4),
  ("c", 3, 5),
  ("d", 1, 3),
  ("d", 2, 3)
).toDF("ID", "STATUS", "COUNT")

df
  .groupBy($"ID")
  .pivot("STATUS")
  .agg(sum($"COUNT"))
  .na.fill(0)
  .orderBy($"ID")
  .show()

+---+---+---+---+
| ID|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  3|  2|  0|
|  b|  0|  4|  0|
|  c|  0|  0|  5|
|  d|  3|  3|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you mind telling me what was unclear about it (not arguing just want constructive criticism). I correctly pivoted the table, and I felt I put enough data to make the question clear. I just had not much of an idea on how to approach this.

Comment: @NutellaAddict Well `a` appears twice in your expected output, while `c`and `d` are missing. You don't describe the logic you want to implement to get to that expected output from your given input

Comment: Doh! did not notice that. Thanks, updated for future readers.